# Database in object-oriented design?

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis

Where do databases fit into object-oriented design? Lets say for example I had a articles database simple straight to the point, my use case diagram had scenarios for search articles, view article, and create article.

Should I have an article class with a connection to the database within the class or just a global database class so that other classes say user class can access the same connection?

Also should I use tables as objects such as article being it's own data object then having a class like ArticleApi for CRUD operations?

Another also if anyone has any start-to-finish object-oriented analysis and design tutorials that would be great.

Sorry for such a novice question I come from procedural programming practices and trying to move into the object-orientation part of software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify any particular platform, so it's not gonna be a very accurate answer.

> Where do databases fit into object-oriented design?

I guess we're talking about [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), right? Well, they don't. This is why we need [ORM software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), like [Hibernate for Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) or [Doctrine for PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29).

> Should I have an article class with a connection to the database within the class or just a global database class so that other classes say user class can access the same connection?
>
> Also should I use tables as objects such as article being it's own data object then having a class like ArticleApi for CRUD operations?

There are basically two common approaches for ORM architecture:

- [Data Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern), where your domain objects are just plain-old objects, without any dependencies to ORM/database. You should model your model in OO-way and then map it into your database. You've got a separate set of objects (EntityManagers) for dealing with actual persistance.
- [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), where your domain objects are tightly coupled with ORM and they provide a set of methods on their own for handling database-related operations.

In my personal opinion data mapper approach is superior to active record as it follows [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles. But active record might be very usefull as well.

---

You should generally remember that your domain model (object oriented) and database model (rdbms) are two different things that have to be modeled with a different guidelines.

Comment: I could hug you right now, very informative and yes I was talking about RDBMS MySQL to be specific

Comment: @Crozin Can I confirm - are you advising that the data for the application should be designed and constructed separately as a RDBMS database using an ERD data model and the OO designed application mapped to the database using ORM?  Is there no other way?

Comment: @AJF Yeah, if you're dealing with non-trivial system this is usually more beneficial approach than attempting to somehow merge those two distinct models.

Comment: @Crozin Thanks for response. Agreed on non-trivial as in if system simple enough to map class to table then fine otherwise another layer of manipulation is required.  What about LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct answer - all depends on application you are building. You can use [Transaction Script](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) approach (which is pretty procedural) for simplest applications.

Then you can evolve to [Table Module](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html) - approach which uses class for each table in database, and that class is responsible for managing all data from table.

For more complex applications you will have [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) (usually even before you will have database). And you will need [Data Mapper](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) to map your Domain Model classes to tables in Database (you can map single class to many tables and vice versa). With power of modern [Object Relational Mappers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) usage of Domain Model become much easier, because most part of this mapping is done automatically. Some tools like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) in .NET even allow you to generate Domain Model from Database tables.